Textbox User Control with custom property to binding not working
I have a user control made up of a TextBox "txtClientCode" inside a stack panel control and it has a property called Value
public string Value
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { 
        SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        this.txtClientCode.Text = value;
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string),
        typeof(uClientTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

Now in my window I have the following Code
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <my:uClientTextBox Height="23" x:Name="uClientTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
        ClientNameLabel="{Binding ElementName=label1}" Value="{Binding Path=ClientCode}"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1"  Content="{Binding Path=ClientCode}"/>
</StackPanel>

The Client Code is displayed in the label called "label1" but in the user control "uClientTextBox", the function to set the value property is not being called to the code ClientCode is never shown.
Any idea please?
Thanks
Ivan

The Value property setter is not called when the property is set by a Binding. You have to register a PropertyChangedCallback.

As an alternative, you may simply bind the txtClientCode's Text property like Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}".
